# TypeScript Interface and union type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm learning typescript from a course on frontendmasters, and it says (from [here](https://www.typescript-training.com/course/fundamentals-v3/07-interfaces-and-type-aliases/#interfaces))

> An interface is a way of defining an object type. An “object type” can
> be thought of as, “an instance of a class could conceivably look like
> this”.
>
> For example, string | number is not an object type, because it makes
> use of the union type operator.

But then I saw a react example (from somewhere else)

```js
// Header.tsx
interface Props {
  title: string | number
  color?: string
}
function Header(props: Props) {
  return <header style={{ color: props.color || "red" }}>{props.title}</header>
}
export default Header
```

```js
// App.tsx
import Header from "./Header"

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header title="My Website" />
      <Header title="Boo" color="blue" />
      <Header title={12345} color="green" />
    </div>
  )
}
```

It uses `|` in `interface Props`, there's no error and it works. Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: IMHO, the tutorial example is indeed misleading. A comparison with _primitive_ types would have been more relevant. A union is used for "composite" types, whether "object-like" or primitive.

Comment: Just want to be clear, the react code example isn't from Mike North. I got it from somewhere else.

Comment: That's... quite an odd way of wording things... Really, an "object type" is any type that isn't defining a primitive or function... However, saying things like "`{ foo: number } | { bar: string }` isn't an object type" is rather a controversial topic. Sure, it's a union type, but it's a union of two object types... so it should still be an object type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found out what I misunderstood. From [tektutorialshub](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/typescript/interface-vs-type-alias-in-typescript/)

> Type alias can give a name to a union type. In this example
> stringOrNumber is a name for the union type of string | number

```js
type stringOrNumber = string | number
```

> We cannot do that using the interface.
>
> You can also create union types of complex types like objects or
> interfaces etc. (...)

So it's about the interface itself can't be an union type. But a property of the interface can be an union type. So what Mike wrote on his site is correct. I just need an example to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

An "interface" defines the "shape of object", while an union type `title: string | number` means, the property "title" is either  a `string` or `number`, and so you can give title either a string or number value:

```
interface Props {
  title: string | number
  color?: string // this is optional
}

// example:
const myProps1: Props = {
  title: "some_string" // string type
}
const title1 = myProps1.title // returns a string

const myProps2: Props = {
  title: 10 // number type
}
const title2 = myProps2.title // returns a number
```

So in the React, this is expected:

```
<Header title="My Website" /> // optional property "color" omited <- ok

<Header title="Boo" color="blue" /> // pass string value to "title" <- ok

<Header title={12345} color="green" /> // pass number value to "title" <- ok
```